# Ggplot2 doesn't print all

Tags: r

I don't understand why my code doesn't work:

```
    if(formula=="ValueA"){
      df<-melt(f,id =c("ValueA"))
      colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'variable'] <- 'Time'

      if(yaxis=="YA"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YA'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YA, fill=ValueA))}
      if(yaxis=="YB"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YB'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YB, fill=ValueA))} 
      if(yaxis=="YC"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YC'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YC, fill=ValueA))} 
      if(yaxis=="YD"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YD'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YD, fill=ValueA))}

      if(type=="line"){
        pl + geom_line(aes(color=ValueA,group=ValueA)) +theme(
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ ggtitle(paste(title))+  YD theme( panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "right")+guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=1))+scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)  
      }
      if(type=="bar"){
        pl + geom_bar(stat="identity") +theme(
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ ggtitle(paste(title))+  YD theme( panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "right")+guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1))+scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)    
      }  
    }
    if(formula=="ValueB"){
      df<-melt(f,id =c("ValueB"))
      colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'variable'] <- 'Time'

      if(yaxis=="YA"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YA'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YA, fill=ValueB))}
      if(yaxis=="YB"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YB'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YB, fill=ValueB))} 
      if(yaxis=="YC"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YC'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YC, fill=ValueB))} 
      if(yaxis=="YD"){
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'value'] <- 'YD'
        pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YD, fill=ValueB))}

      if(type=="line"){
        pl+ geom_line(aes(color=ValueB,group=ValueB))+theme(
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ ggtitle(paste(title))+  YD theme( panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "right")+guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=1)) +scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)   
      }
      if(type=="bar"){
        pl + geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme(
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ ggtitle(paste(title))+  YD theme( panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "right")+guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1)) +scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)   
      }  
    } 


  print(pl)
}
Plotsf<-Plots(Df,"Title","line","YA")
```

The problem is that it doesn't read the `pl +` under the line in which i declare to want a line or a bar plot, and it just prints an empty graph with only the names of the x and y axes. By printing the whole

```
pl<- ggplot(df, aes(Time, YD, fill=ValueA))+ geom_bar(stat="identity") +theme(
              axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ ggtitle(paste(title))+  YD theme( panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "right")+guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1))+scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)
```

The output is perfect. Someone can explaine me why the `pl +` doesn't work?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe try `pl <- pl + ...`instead? By the way, is this a function where the first lines are missing? Looks a bit distorted from indent ...

Comment: @Dilettant It worked...Thanks, sorry but i'm a noob with this stuff.

Comment: I made an answer out of it. You may accept it if you like ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is to carry over the variable and instead of just writing:

```
pl + ... added stuff
```

which goes to nowhere ... use instead:

```
pl <- pl + ... added stuff
```